# Scaling animation on different screen size

Tags: android, animation

Hey I have the following problem whan I animate my floating buttons - namely they are scaling badly. First of all, fab buttons on the second Image are higher than they should. Event main floating button with "+" is not rotating. I anyone know how to deal with it please answer me.

Image left HTC One MAX, screen HD - SKD21 lolipop, emulator 768x1280 SKD 17 jelly bean
[image]

my code in Activity.PhotoGallery

```
 private void showFabs(){
    Animation show_fab_photo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab_add_photo_show);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fabAddPhoto.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.bottomMargin += (int) (fabAddPhoto.getHeight() * 1.7);
    fabAddPhoto.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    fabAddPhoto.startAnimation(show_fab_photo);
    fabAddPhoto.setClickable(true);

    Animation show_fab_gallery = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab_add_from_gallery_show);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsGallery = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fabAddFromGallery.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsGallery.bottomMargin += (int) (fabAddFromGallery.getHeight() * 3.4);
    fabAddFromGallery.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsGallery);
    fabAddFromGallery.startAnimation(show_fab_gallery);
    fabAddFromGallery.setClickable(true);

    Animation rotateFabAdd = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab_gallery_show);
    fabAdd.startAnimation(rotateFabAdd);
}

private void hideFabs(){
    Animation hide_fab_photo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab_add_photo_hide);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fabAddPhoto.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.bottomMargin -= (int) (fabAddPhoto.getHeight() * 1.7);
    fabAddPhoto.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    fabAddPhoto.startAnimation(hide_fab_photo);
    fabAddPhoto.setClickable(false);

    Animation hide_fab_gallery = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab_add_from_gallery_hide);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsGallery = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fabAddFromGallery.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsGallery.bottomMargin -= (int) (fabAddFromGallery.getHeight() * 3.4);
    fabAddFromGallery.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsGallery);
    fabAddFromGallery.startAnimation(hide_fab_gallery);
    fabAddFromGallery.setClickable(false);

    Animation rotateFabAdd = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab_gallery_hide);
    fabAdd.startAnimation(rotateFabAdd);
}
```

And my animations XML files
**Fab with camera**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <!-- Rotate -->
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromDegrees="30"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="0"></rotate>

    <!--Move-->
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="170%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"></translate>


    <!--Fade In-->
    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"></alpha>

</set>
```

**Fab with image**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <!-- Rotate -->
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromDegrees="30"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="0"></rotate>

    <!--Move-->
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="340%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"></translate>

    <!--Fade In-->
    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"></alpha>
</set>
```